# Kivy: Why do some of my buttons obscure the rectangles I paint on them?

Tags: kivy

I want a GridLayout of 3x3 Buttons, with each Button decorated by a coloured Rectangle. For some reason, some of the Buttons are "on top of" their Rectangles, obscuring them, while others are below as they should be. See screenshot. I looked at z-index and the index argument in add_widget, but I can't see the index would be wrong in the first place.

```
#!/usr/bin/env kivy

'''Why are some of the rectangles obscured by the buttons?'''

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.config import Config
from kivy.graphics import Color, Rectangle
from random import random as r

class ImageButton(Button):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ImageButton, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        side = 80 # smaller than button, to make it easy to see what's happening
        print self.x
        with self.canvas:
            Color(r(), r(), r())
            Rectangle(pos=self.convert_coords(0, 0), size=(side, side))

    def convert_coords(self, x, y):
        """Convert relative [0-1] widget coords to absolute (pixel-valued)
        window coords. FIXME this should be handled by
        self.to_parent."""
        w = int(Config.get('graphics', 'width'))
        h = int(Config.get('graphics', 'height'))
        phx = self.pos_hint['x']
        phy = self.pos_hint['y']
        shx = self.size_hint[0]
        shy = self.size_hint[1]
        i = w * (phx + x * shx)
        j = h * (phy + y * shy)
        return i, j

    def hello(self, i, j, *largs):
        print i, j

class Cells(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Cells, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for i in range(self.cols):
            for j in range(self.rows):
                cell = ImageButton(size_hint=(1./self.cols, 1./self.rows),
                                   pos_hint={'x':i/float(self.cols), 'y':j/float(self.rows)})
                cell.bind(on_release=lambda *x: cell.hello(i, j))
                self.add_widget(cell)

class Main(App):
    def build(self):
        return Cells(cols=3, rows=3)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Config.set('graphics', 'width',  '300')
    Config.set('graphics', 'height', '300')
    Main().run()
```

[image: Screenshot]

I'm using Kivy 1.8.0 on OSX.

EDIT: current working version is below.

```
#!/usr/bin/env kivy

'''Using kvlang and GridLayout correctly simplifies and avoids the error'''

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.config import Config
from kivy.graphics import Color, Rectangle

kv_string = """
#:import r random.random

<ImageButton>:
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: r(), r(), r(), 1
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
"""

class ImageButton(Button):
    pass

class Cells(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Cells, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for i in range(self.cols):
            for j in range(self.rows):
                self.add_widget(ImageButton())

class Main(App):
    def __init__(self, cols, rows, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Main, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.cols = cols
        self.rows = rows
    def build(self):
        return Cells(cols=self.cols, rows=self.rows)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    cols = 3
    rows = 3
    Config.set('graphics', 'width',  str(cols * 100))
    Config.set('graphics', 'height', str(rows * 100))
    Builder.load_string(kv_string)
    Main(cols, rows).run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why do some of my buttons obscure the rectangles I paint on them?

The direct answer is that they don't - they obscure the rectangles of different buttons. Your problem is that your convert_coords function does not place the rectangles in the same place as their button; the GridLayout *ignores* the pos_hint and fills in the buttons from the top left, while your code assumes the buttons are filled in from the bottom left.

That is, the rectangle in the bottom left is the first one drawn (by the first button), but that button is actually placed in the top right. The button in the bottom left is actually the *seventh* drawn, so it appears on top of the rectangle.

You could resolve this by fixing your coordinate mathematics, but actually your whole process is not good - you are fighting kivy rather than working with it. The layout already performs positioning maths internally, giving the buttons the right position, and it's much easier to simply take advantage of this.

```
class ImageButton(Button):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ImageButton, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        side = 80 # smaller than button, to make it easy to see what's happening
        print self.x
        with self.canvas:
            Color(r(), r(), r())
            self.rect = Rectangle(pos=self.pos, size=self.size)
        self.bind(pos=self.update_rect, size=self.update_rect)

    def update_rect(self, instance, value):
        self.rect.pos = self.pos
        self.rect.size = self.size
```

This simply lets the layout do the work; when the button is positioned, its size and pos properties may be changed, and if that happens the update_rect method is automatically called which repositions the rectangle appopriately. This has the additional advantage that it will continue working if your window doesn't have the exact size you preset.

This is even easier if you use kv language (which I recommend!):

```
class ImageButton(Button):
    pass  # You don't need to do *anything* in python!
```

...and kv code:

```
#:import r random.random

<ImageButton>:
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: r(), r(), r(), 1
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
```

This is even shorter and clearer, and the rectangle pos and size will automatically be updated to match the button pos and size because kv automatically creates the right binding.

Comment: Thank you. Yes it looks like I need to re-read a lot of docs. I've added the current version to my question.